# How To Compare/Match Handwriting Signature In Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I want to compare two images.  I've made an application to get a user's handwritten signature, and then save it as a JPG.  But now I want to be able to use this image to compare it to another signature to determine if they are the same or not.

I don't know how to do this, and don't know where to start.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Comparing images and comparing signatures to detect forgery is completely a different question. This question should not be closed, because comparing pixel to pixel is not something done is signature/hand writing verification.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare your images byte by byte to see if they are the same.